# Extjs - Scroll to last row (selected item)

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4.1

I want to scroll to last row or selected item or rowIndex
I try some case like:

```
                grid.setScrollTop(rowIndex); // not working

                grid.getView().focusRow(rowIndex);// not working

                // not working
                var idx = this.getStore().indexOfId(rowIndex);
                var rowEl = this.getView().getRow(idx);
                rowEl.scrollIntoView(this.getGridEl(), false);
```

all of them are not working, how can i do that thanks

**Edit:**
I have a window include a gridpanel and when i add a new item i want scroll of window to last thanks

**Edit 2:**
see my example: **http://jsfiddle.net/h9Dy9/** When i add some new items scroll of window must move to last or select items.

Comment: Are you using a buffered store?

Comment: I try with local store (ArrayStore) and i don't init width or height for my gridpanel, I using autoScroll: true for my Ext.window.Window

Answer (score 0):

Last row, it means the bottom of the grid right?

I tried to use this, and it works:

```
var scrollPosition = 100;   
YourGrid.getEl().down('.x-grid-view').scroll('bottom', scrollPosition, true);
```

I found this from [Grid -scrollTo bottom](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?235385-Grid-scrollTo-bottom)